# Protobuf map build error CS1061: MapField does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, build, protocol-buffers

Consider the following .proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package Greet;
option csharp_namespace = "Greet";
 
message Address {
    map<int32, string> AreaInfo = 1; 
}
```

Build this proto to cs file,but there is a CS1061 Error after compilation:

```
pb\Greet.cs(174,17,174,26): error CS1061:'MapField<int, string>' does not contain a definition for 'MergeFrom' and no accessible extension method 'MergeFrom' accepting a first argument of type 'MapField<int, string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBbv.png)

My protoc verison is **25.2**!  When i use **3.4.0** version, there is no Error!
What should i do if i want use latest version to resolve this error? please,thanks

Comment: You improperly typed the error message. Why not copy and paste it from the compiler output dump?

Comment: ok!

1>D:\work\Remote\pb\Greet.cs(174,17,174,26): error CS1061: 'MapField<int, string>' does not contain a definition for 'MergeFrom' and no accessible extension method 'MergeFrom' accepting a first argument of type 'MapField<int, string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the error as a code, formatted text in the question.

Comment: This was a bug 1.5 years ago https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10327. It may be regression.

Comment: sorry , I just got started with this and don't how to format !
 thanks your answer ,  then I'll use history version for now !  Thank you again

Comment: Which protobuf version are you using in your csproj file? I experienced the same Issue when I was using an outdated version that was too old to be compatible with my protoc version.